# r How do I allow assignment from commands below?

Tags: r, list, dependencies

I have a list `hx[[i]]` with 150 elements. My script gradually populates this list but the list is referencing a "real-world" list. For this reason, the list has to be in a set order (alphabetized by the real-world list) in the script for readability. Further, the list elements depend on other list elements (with the exception of `hx[[1]]`) and dependency is in such a way that some elements depend on elements below in the script. For example,

```
hx[[2]] <- hx[[3]] + 4

hx[[3]] <- hx[[1]]

hx[[4]] <- hx[[2]] - 2
```

Edit: N.B. each assignment operation will have at most one `hx[[i]]` on the right-hand side. Obviously that `hx[[i]]` may itself depend on another `hx[[j]]` but the following sort of thing never occurs

```
hx[[k]] <- hx[[i]] + hx[[j]]
```

Right now, what I am doing is stupid but seemingly effective (I'm wondering if there's a better way). I assign all elements in the list to `hx[[1]]` then I run the code as written **150 times** so that the reverse dependencies are surely used. An example with just 4 list items is below

```
xx <- c(0,0,1,2,3)
hx[[1]] <- xx
for (i in 1:4) { hx[[i]] <- hx[[1]]}

for (i in 1:4){
hx[[1]] <- xx

hx[[2]] <- hx[[3]] + xx

hx[[3]] <- hx[[1]]

hx[[4]] <- hx[[2]] - 2*xx

# More assignments similar

}
```

Now, I'm pretty sure this works. But (1) it seems incredibly wasteful and (2) it might not. Do I need to run it more often? What is a better way to do this?

Comment: You do realise that you can sort a list after it's been created, yes? You don't have to create it in a predefined way to satisfy a readability constraint; you can create it so that it makes the task of populating it easier, and then reorder it. Also, please post a sample of your data and dependencies that makes for reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

1. Figure out the order in which your elements depend on each other: ie, `x1 -> x2`, `x2 -> x3`, and so on.
2. Create your list in that order.
3. Use a `for` loop from top to bottom to initialise your elements.
4. Reorder your list to fit your readability constraint.

Comment: You were concerned about waste. If it turns out you don't care about waste, then put another `for(j in 1:150) {...}` around your original loop and iterate 22500 times. If your initialisation code really is as simple as you've posted, this will be instantaneous on modern hardware.